# How can i check if char equals some string

Tags: java

I need to get the user input and replace every character `"e"` with `"#"`. Since Java doesn't allow us to use index in String, therefore I decided to use `charAt(index)` and now I get error saying char cannot be dereferenced.

I want to learn how to do it with loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Replacing{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
        String name = input.next();
        String name2= "";
        int index = 0;
        int length = name.length();
        while (index < length){
            char a = name.charAt(index);
            if( a.equals("e")){
                name2 = name2 + "#";}
            else
            {name2 = name2+cha;}
            index++;}
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to call `String.replace`

Comment: Well,Thanks. i can use that if thts the only solution. But im learning how to replace it using Loops.

Comment: `name = name.replace("e", "#");`

Comment: Replace is the best guess, if you want to replace within a loop, try the `StringBuilder` class. It has nice string manipulation features

Answer (score 1):

Found the Solution  IT was actually Really simple: 
HAD TO USE == operator and had to use single quote NOT Double Quote since that give "char cannot be dereferenced " error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PS9Q3{
public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your name: ");
String name = input.next();
String name2= "";
int index = 0;
int length = name.length();
while (index < length){
   char a = name.charAt(index);
     if( a=='e'){ //<--------HAD TO CHANGE FROM DOUBLE QUOTE INTO SINGLE QUOTE
       name2 = name2 + "#";}
     else
     {name2 = name2+a;}
     index++;}
System.out.println(name2);
```

}

}